# div direct child of body, both height 100%, gap above and below the div

Tags: html, css

I know questions like this are asked a lot.  I did look for a solution and attempted some of them.  Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/hgxKh/6/

And here it is below

```
<body>
<div id="middle">   
</div>
</body>

html, body, #middle
{
height:100%;
padding:0%;
}
body
{
background-color:#cccccc;
} 
#middle
{
    margin-left:18%;
    margin-right:18%;
    background-color:#5DBCD2;
}
```

I tried using jQuery to alert the heights of both body and #middle, and allegedly they're the same. I experimented with setting various elements' positions to relative, setting min-height... no luck so far.

Basically, why is there visible gray above and below the blue?

Thanks

Comment: In case you aren't aware, general policy is to select the answer that you deem best/most useful as the accepted answer, and additionally upvote all correct/useful answers (including the accepted answer). By only upvoting one and not selecting any as correct, it is more difficult for future readers to see which answers to use if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding margin:0px;

```
html, body, #middle {
    height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Great, that did it.  So is there some sort of implicit margin on some elements if you don't specify otherwise?

Comment: Pretty much, depends on the browser a bit, check out: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: nb. if values are zero, you dont need to specify units

Answer (score 0):

### What's Going On

[image]

Some browsers will give `html` and/or `body` `padding` or `margin`. Right now, you are setting `padding` to `0`. You need to additionally set `margin:0` to your code.

### Code

#### Current:

```
html, body, #middle{
    height:100%;
    padding:0%;
}
```

#### Working:

```
html, body, #middle{
    height:100%;
    padding:0%;
    margin:0;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgxKh/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
height:100%;
padding:0%;
    margin: 0%;
}
```

add margin.

Answer (score 0):

add margin:0

```
html, body, #middle
{
    height:100%;
    padding:0%;
    margin:0;
}
```